# Spring Eclipse Kepler, Eclipse Juno error creating a controller bean

Tags: spring, controller, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

I worked with Eclipse Juno, Spring 3.2.6 and weblogic 10.3.6.
Now I changed Eclipse Kepler and I imported the project new Eclipse Kepler.
I continue working with weblogic 10.3.6

Deploy in Eclipse Juno is correct.

But in Eclipse Kepler I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:715)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:522)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:714)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:700)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:870)
    ... 53 more
<17-jun-2016 08H55' CEST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activityController' defined in file [C:\Users\excp0019\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\eusurvey\beadep\test1\eusurvey\WEB-INF\classes\com\ec\survey\controller\ActivityController.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class com.ec.survey.controller.ActivityController] failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:875)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:715)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:522)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:117)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I read the link

```
http://www.tomred.net/java/sun.reflect.annotation.typenotpresentexceptionproxy.html
```

I have a question.

Activity controller is

```
package com.ec.survey.controller;

import com.ec.survey.model.*;
import com.ec.survey.model.administration.User;
import com.ec.survey.model.survey.Survey;
import com.ec.survey.service.*;
import com.ec.survey.tools.ConversionTools;
import com.ec.survey.tools.Ucs2Utf8;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{shortname}/management")
public class ActivityController extends BasicController {

    @Resource(name = "sessionService")
    private SessionService sessionService;

    @Resource(name = "administrationService")
    private AdministrationService administrationService;

    @Resource(name = "surveyService")
    private SurveyService surveyService;

    @Resource(name = "activityService")
    private ActivityService activityService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/activity")
    public ModelAndView activity(@PathVariable String shortname, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Form form;
        User user = sessionService.getCurrentUser(request);
```

Doesn't my project find every bean?. Or is a annotation problem?

How do I have configure Eclipse Keppler to find the beans?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Did you check your java version settings? Make sure they are set correctly